# What is causing MySQL swap usage and eventually oom_killer

Tags: mysql, linux, out-of-memory, mariadb, centos7

We are struggling with a problem that appeared a few days ago. oom_killer started killing mysqld and reported full memory and swap usage. The system should have enough memory for mysql to operate without swapping.

Any insight into why memory is consumed so much more than the innodb_buffer_pool_size would be highly appreciated?

- CentOS 7.2.1511 x86_64
- MariaDB 10.1.17 x86_64
- 150GB RAM 8 CPU
- VMWare vSphere 6

my.cnf

```
[MYSQLD]
# Added for xtrabackup
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:1000M:autoextend
user=mysql
basedir=/usr/
datadir=/var/lib/mysql/data
tmpdir=/var/lib/mysql/tmp
ignore-db-dirs=lost+found
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
pid-file=mysqld.pid
port=3306
log-error=error.log
slow_query_log=1
long_query_time=10
log-queries-not-using-indexes=1
### INNODB OPTIONS 
innodb-buffer-pool-size=110G # Used to be 124GB which has worked for a long time
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=2
innodb-file-per-table=1
innodb-data-file-path = ibdata1:1000M:autoextend
## You may want to tune the below depending on number of cores and disk sub
innodb-read-io-threads=4
innodb-write-io-threads=4
innodb-doublewrite=1
innodb-log-file-size=1024M
innodb-log-buffer-size=96M
innodb-buffer-pool-instances=8
innodb-log-files-in-group=2
innodb-thread-concurrency=0
#innodb-file-format=barracuda
innodb-flush-method = O_DIRECT
# Deprecated
#innodb-locks-unsafe-for-binlog=1
innodb-autoinc-lock-mode=2
## avoid statistics update when doing e.g show tables
innodb-stats-on-metadata=0
default-storage-engine=innodb

server-id=1
binlog_format=row
expire-logs-days=2
log-bin
log-basename=master
key_buffer_size = 24M
tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
max-allowed-packet = 512M
skip-name-resolve
memlock=0
sysdate-is-now=1
max-connections=512
thread-cache-size=512
query-cache-type = 0
query-cache-size = 0
table-open_cache=1024
lower-case-table-names=0
performance_schema=on
#wait_timeout=3650
#connection closed errors
wait_timeout=28800
```

df -h

```
Filesystem                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root            77G  8.4G   69G  11% /
devtmpfs                           76G     0   76G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              76G     0   76G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              76G  8.6M   76G   1% /run
tmpfs                              76G     0   76G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/mysql-lvol001         800G  478G  323G  60% /var/lib/mysql
/dev/sda1                         497M  276M  221M  56% /boot
tmpfs                              16G     0   16G   0% /run/user/0
```

/var/log/messages

```
Sep 25 11:42:31 xsql1md kernel: mysqld invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x42d0, order=3, oom_score_adj=0
Sep 25 11:42:31 xsql1md kernel: mysqld cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Sep 25 11:42:31 xsql1md kernel: CPU: 5 PID: 18376 Comm: mysqld Not tainted 3.10.0-327.36.1.el7.x86_64 #1
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 09/21/2015
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: ffff8825a3352280 0000000074fbe109 ffff881f875278b0 ffffffff81636301
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: ffff881f87527940 ffffffff8163129c ffff88230babe3c0 0000000000000010
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: ffffffff8197e700 ffff881f87527990 0000000000000001 ffff8825a503c220
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: Call Trace:
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [<ffffffff81636301>] dump_stack+0x19/0x1b
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [<ffffffff8163129c>] dump_header+0x8e/0x214
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [<ffffffff8116d21e>] oom_kill_process+0x24e/0x3b0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [<ffffffff8116da46>] out_of_memory+0x4b6/0x4f0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [<ffffffff81173c36>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0xaa6/0xba0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [<ffffffff811b4aca>] alloc_pages_current+0xaa/0x170
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [<ffffffff81515060>] sk_page_frag_refill+0x70/0x160
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [<ffffffff81577763>] tcp_sendmsg+0x263/0xc20
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [<ffffffff815a1c04>] inet_sendmsg+0x64/0xb0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [<ffffffff81288ba3>] ? selinux_socket_sendmsg+0x23/0x30
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [<ffffffff815112a0>] sock_sendmsg+0xb0/0xf0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [<ffffffff81511811>] SYSC_sendto+0x121/0x1c0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [<ffffffff8163b3b8>] ? __schedule+0x2d8/0x900
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [<ffffffff8151229e>] SyS_sendto+0xe/0x10
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [<ffffffff81646a09>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: Mem-Info:
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    2: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    3: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    4: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    5: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    6: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    7: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    4: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    5: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    6: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    7: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: Node 0 Normal per-cpu:
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   1
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    4: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    5: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    6: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: CPU    7: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: active_anon:37766688 inactive_anon:1096008 isolated_anon:256#012 active_file:127 inactive_file:502 isolated_file:0#012 unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:13 unstable:0#012 free:173856 slab_reclaimable:13999 slab_unreclaimable:11990#012 mapped:0 shmem:102 pagetables:83121 bounce:0#012 free_cma:0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: Node 0 DMA free:15860kB min:4kB low:4kB high:4kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15992kB managed:15908kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:16kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2806 153956 153956
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: Node 0 DMA32 free:605088kB min:1228kB low:1532kB high:1840kB active_anon:1797784kB inactive_anon:456032kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:3129280kB managed:2875692kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:4kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:1748kB slab_unreclaimable:920kB kernel_stack:192kB pagetables:9096kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 151149 151149
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: Node 0 Normal free:74476kB min:66344kB low:82928kB high:99516kB active_anon:149268968kB inactive_anon:3928000kB active_file:508kB inactive_file:2008kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):1024kB isolated(file):0kB present:157286400kB managed:154777020kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:52kB mapped:0kB shmem:408kB slab_reclaimable:54248kB slab_unreclaimable:47024kB kernel_stack:6944kB pagetables:323388kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:1870 all_unreclaimable? no
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: Node 0 DMA: 1*4kB (U) 0*8kB 1*16kB (U) 1*32kB (U) 1*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (R) 3*4096kB (M) = 15860kB
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: Node 0 DMA32: 110*4kB (UEM) 71*8kB (UEM) 95*16kB (UEM) 65*32kB (UEM) 399*64kB (UEM) 272*128kB (EM) 144*256kB (UM) 73*512kB (UEM) 51*1024kB (UM) 0*2048kB 101*4096kB (UMR) = 605120kB
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: Node 0 Normal: 7935*4kB (UEM) 4299*8kB (UEM) 402*16kB (UEM) 68*32kB (UEM) 14*64kB (UM) 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 75636kB
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: 34049 total pagecache pages
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: 33035 pages in swap cache
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: Swap cache stats: add 3213156, delete 3180121, find 33753/44214
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: Free swap  = 0kB
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: Total swap = 3145724kB
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: 40107918 pages RAM
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: 690763 pages reserved
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes swapents oom_score_adj name
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [  581]     0   581     9204      101      21       62             0 systemd-journal
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [  609]     0   609    69151        0      32      412             0 lvmetad
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [  616]     0   616    11635        1      24      647         -1000 systemd-udevd
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [  773]     0   773    12797        2      25      107         -1000 auditd
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [  795]     0   795     4830       34      13       45             0 irqbalance
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [  796]     0   796    55471        0      40      191             0 rsyslogd
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [  797]    81   797     9786        0      19      150          -900 dbus-daemon
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [  804]     0   804    62201      102      64      300             0 vmtoolsd
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [  805]     0   805    80995        0      77     4258             0 firewalld
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [  806]     0   806     7646       15      18       71             0 systemd-logind
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [  807]    70   807     8043        0      20       76             0 avahi-daemon
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [  811]    70   811     8043        0      19       63             0 avahi-daemon
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [  812]     0   812    50842       10      39      114             0 gssproxy
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [  874]     0   874   132085       53      77      485             0 NetworkManager
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [  973]     0   973    13266        0      28      149             0 wpa_supplicant
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [  975]   999   975   133079        0      57     1763             0 polkitd
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [ 1397]     0  1397    20640        0      43      214         -1000 sshd
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [ 1399]     0  1399   138291       88      88     2556             0 tuned
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [ 1420]    65  1420   110056        0      47      260             0 nslcd
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [ 1444]    29  1444    11652        0      26      213             0 rpc.statd
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [ 1455]    32  1455    16227       15      34      122             0 rpcbind
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [ 1623]     0  1623    31582       21      19      137             0 crond
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [ 1685]     0  1685    27509        1      10       32             0 agetty
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [ 2128]     0  2128    23471       19      45      262             0 master
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [ 2159]    89  2159    24039       19      47      269             0 qmgr
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [12645]     0 12645    37290       14      74      311             0 sshd
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [12649]     0 12649    28879       89      14       41             0 bash
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [18021]   899 18021 53059499 38825145   82029   770667             0 mysqld
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: [18383]    89 18383    24022      273      48        0             0 pickup
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 18021 (mysqld) score 986 or sacrifice child
Sep 25 11:42:32 xsql1md kernel: Killed process 18021 (mysqld) total-vm:212237996kB, anon-rss:155300580kB, file-rss:0kB
Sep 25 11:42:37 xsql1md systemd: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Sep 25 11:42:37 xsql1md systemd: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Sep 25 11:42:37 xsql1md systemd: mariadb.service failed.
Sep 25 11:42:42 xsql1md systemd: mariadb.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 25 11:42:42 xsql1md systemd: Starting MariaDB database server...
Sep 25 11:42:43 xsql1md mysqld: 2016-09-25 11:42:43 139704796522624 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.17-MariaDB) starting as process 18575 ...
```

free -m (now)

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         153973       15558      135954           3        2459      138145
Swap:          3071          55        3016
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100873/oom-killer-killed-mysql-server

Comment: Thanks for the reference. We discovered that MariaDB was using as much as 2GB per process when we used the latest MariaDB 1.5.2 JDBC driver. MySQL driver had a much bigger memory footprint on the application server, but didn't effect the database as much.

We finally solved our issue by using an older MariaDB 1.2.3 driver, but we will continue to try and find a suitable memory/configuration that would under no circumstances cause oom.

Comment: For reference, here's the SQL to find process memory usage (only MariaDB as far as I know):

`SELECT HOST,COMMAND,TIME,STATE,INFO,MEMORY_USED / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) as MEMORY_USED_GB from information_schema.processlist ORDER BY MEMORY_USED desc LIMIT 20;`

Answer (score 1):

What solved our issue was setting the MariaDB JDBC driver parameter *useServerPrepStmts=false*. The developer had not camelcased it, so it was ignored.

Answer (score 0):

In the OS, set `swappiness = 1`.  This *may* prevent the unnecessary kill.

Meanwhile, could you provide `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` at some busy time when it might crash.  The value you show in my.cnf *seem* reasonable for 150GB of RAM; maybe something subtle is going on.

I'm curious why you are in a VM.  VMs are usually used to carve out small pieces of a machine, not a 150GB piece.  (And note that there is a non-trivial performance penalty for VM.)

Comment: Sorry for not noticing your questions. I have provided the solution that works for us as an answer. Why we are using a VM is quite simple: When the database was created 15 years ago, it used <10GB of memory. The simplest and most cost effective solution to add resources along the way has been virtualization. 150GB is 30% of the memory load on the physical server, so it is a piece of the server.